# Maven exclusion is persistent

Tags: java, maven

I have this in my app POM:

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
                    <artifactId>errai-cdi-jetty</artifactId>
                    <version>${errai.version}</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jetty-naming</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
```

However, I can still see `jetty-plus`, and `jetty-naming` in the `WEB-INF\lib` folder (i.e after `mvn clean install`). What are the ways to identify how to fix this issue.

**Update:**

However mvn dependency:tree shows:

```
[INFO] +- org.jboss.errai:errai-cdi-jetty:jar:3.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.2.0.RC0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.0.RC0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.0.RC0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.2.0.RC0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.2.0.RC0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.2.0.RC0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.2.0.RC0:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.2.0.RC0:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:9.2.0.RC0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.0.RC0:compile
```

Comment: First, check your dependency hierarchy and make sure you aren't picking those artifacts up from something else you're including.

Comment: Possibly they are transient dependencies under a different group/artifactId. Check mvn dependency:tree to see ALL the dependencies Maven will pull in and where they are coming from.

Comment: @Gimby I think you mean transitive, not transient ;-)

Comment: Note that errai-cdi-jetty has scope provided.

Comment: @lpratlong very good catch, that makes it almost certain the dependencies are coming in -transitively- (thanks andre) through another dependency. My earlier mvn dependency:tree suggestion should show where exactly.

Comment: @Ipratlong sorry the provided should not be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `mvn dependency:tree` on the project you're having problems with. This will print the entire dependency tree and you'll be able to see where the problematic depdendencies are coming from and exclude them in the right place.

I'm guessing you didn't exclude from the correct module (remember that a dependency might come from several modules)

**Edit:** I see you added the `dependency:tree` which is great. Now you need to search your dependencies and continue as I mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with this is to just get your dependencies sorted out as recommended in the comments, but if that is not feasible for some reason, you can also explicitly exclude jar files you don't want by adding an exclusion tag to the maven-war-plugin like this:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/i-dont-want-this.jar</packagingExcludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```